# async Task.Run lambda expression crashes Unity AR app on android but works fine on iOS

Tags: c#, android, ios, unity-game-engine

I am creating an app with Unity 2020.3.4 and ARCore 4.0.12 and Azure Spatial Anchors 2.8.1. It is a cross platform app for Android and iOS. First I created an iOS version where I created a Task.Run(async() =>{  }); lambda expression inside a void function to be able to call Azure Spatial Anchors' async functions. I did it this way, because this function is called on a Unity button press, which does not take async Task, but it does take void's. This worked fine on iOS devices, but once I tested it on an Android device this code crashed the app.

```cs
//Called on Unity UI button press, works fine on IOS, but crashes the app on Android
public void BROKENStartLookingForAnchor()
{
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        if (!hasStartedOnce)
        {
            await StorageManager.instance.InitializeStorage();
            anchorId = await StorageManager.instance.DownloadBlob(blobName);
        }

        spatialAnchorManager.SessionStarted += OnSessionStarted;
        spatialAnchorManager.AnchorLocated += CloudManager_AnchorLocated;

        anchorLocateCriteria = new AnchorLocateCriteria();

        if (spatialAnchorManager.Session == null)
        {
            await spatialAnchorManager.CreateSessionAsync();
            SetAnchorLocateCriteria();
        }

        await spatialAnchorManager.StartSessionAsync();
    });
}
```

It was very hard to figure out the issue at first (I used LogCat to debug), but once I changed my code to the following it worked fine on Android as well.

```cs
//Called on Unity UI button press, because cannot call async Task from Unity button press
public async void StartLookingForAnchor()
{
    await StartLookingForAnchorAsync();
}

private async Task StartLookingForAnchorAsync()
{
    if (!hasStartedOnce)
    {
        await StorageManager.instance.InitializeStorage();
        anchorId = await StorageManager.instance.DownloadBlob(blobName);
    }

    spatialAnchorManager.SessionStarted += OnSessionStarted;
    spatialAnchorManager.AnchorLocated += CloudManager_AnchorLocated;

    anchorLocateCriteria = new AnchorLocateCriteria();

    if (spatialAnchorManager.Session == null)
    {
        await spatialAnchorManager.CreateSessionAsync();
        SetAnchorLocateCriteria();
    }

    await spatialAnchorManager.StartSessionAsync();
}
```

However, even though I fixed the issue I am still not sure why the first option does not work on Android and why the second one does because I am not very familiar with async functions and multi-threading. Can someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 0):

Check out these issues

https://github.com/Azure/azure-spatial-anchors-samples/issues/230
https://github.com/Azure/azure-spatial-anchors-samples/issues/283

Try the workarounds mentioned by Vastja if you're experiencing similar error

Answer (score -1):

`Task.Run(async () => { ... });` returns a `Task`, which is not awaited in your first version, where `BROKENStartLookingForAnchorAsync()` has a return type of just `void`.

In your second version, the `Task` returned by `async Task StartLookingForAnchorAsync()` is awaited (which is made possible by `StartLookingForAnchor()` having a return type of `async void`).

I suspect your first version would also work if you made it return `async void` and made the code `await Task.Run(async () => { ... });`, or just removed the `Task.Run()` wrapping the rest of the code entirely.

Per the [C# async documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/async#return-types), `async void` return types are discouraged, except for in event handlers, which sounds like your use case with the Unity button press.

The [Unity QuickStart tutorials in the Azure Spatial Anchors documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spatial-anchors/unity-overview) could be a good starting point for patterns to use with Unity + ASA.